# Is it possible to prove from the definition of Big O that $2x^3+x^2logx$ is $O(x^3)$? I''m stuck at it please explain me this one.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Is it possible to prove from the definition of big $O$ that $2x^3+x^2logx$ is $O(x^3)$?

Comment: Does n3 mean $n_3$ or $n^3$?

Comment: the question in the body is not the question in the title

Comment: At $0$ or $\infty$?

Comment: That's Big O. I've edited @qbert

Comment: Please anyone explain me this one. I'm stuck at it

Comment: What's your definition? There isn't a unique one. My favourite is $f \in O(g)$ if $\limsup \left|\frac{f}{g} \right| < \infty$

Answer (score 1):

You have that $\log x \leq x$ and hence
$$2x^3 + x^2 \log x \leq 2x^3 + x^2\cdot x = 2x^3 + x^3 = 3x^3$$
and therefore $2x^3 + x^2\log x$ is $\mathcal{O}(x^3).$

Comment: how come logx is less than and equal to x?